# Are black hole regarded as baryonic matter in cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, baryons

Black holes do not have any property as baryonic or non-baryonic matter, as is stated by the no-hair theorem. Regarding conventional theories, in different models of cosmology, like Lambda-CDM, are black holes regarded as baryonic matter, and does the black hole matter significantly affect the baryonic density?

Comment: http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/B/baryonic+matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baryonic doesn't literally mean baryonic. It's a label of convenience for something that behaves in a certain way. The main evidence for dark matter comes from big bang nucleosynthesis (BBN), and from the fact that we need it in order to reconcile the observed rotation curves of galaxies with the observed strength of the CMB fluctuations. In the BBN era, presumably we didn't have any black holes, so the issue doesn't arise. If we want to explain a galaxy's rotation curve, then a black hole is exactly the same as any other star, so it would presumably go on the census as baryonic matter, but in any case black holes are a negligible fraction of baryonic matter, and they always will be. (There is a common misconception that all matter will end up in black holes, which simply isn't true.)

Comment: This answer seems confused about many aspects. It touches on all the right buzz-words, but then combines them in a incoherent way. 1) BBN does not  does not provide evidence for dark matter. It puts a bound on the amount of baryonic matter. 2) Galaxy rotation curves and CMB fluctuations are individual observations that need dark matter to be explained. They do not need dark matter to be reconciled with each other. (Although the fact a similar amount of dark matter solves both certainly strengthens the dark matter hypothesis.)

Comment: 3) Galaxy rotation curves have nothing to measuring the amount of baryonic matter. So that black holes act the same as baryonic matter in this respect is completely irrelevant. 4) There may very well have been black holes during the BBN era, they would however not have affect the relative abundances. So their presence does not matter.